# Using google cloud service account

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I am given a google cloud service account with
    1] A client id
    2] An email id 
    3] Certificate fingerprint
    4] .p12 file

I had a java process previously that was communicating with big query with my own personal email account with client secret file etc. This setup is working just fine.

Now that I have to use this service account, I did not see any client secret provided with this account. I am wondering how am i supposed to integrate this service account into my current process.

I tried to find a bunch of things on google but finally found this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

is this correct way to use this or for service accounts there is something else ? 
Is there a better example somewhere where i can see proper steps to use the info i have to access google cloud from my app with a service account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the link you have is the way to use service account. You need to get the "client secret" from [the developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), in the form of a json or p12 file.

As for example, [storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-storage-docs-xml-api-examples/tree/master/storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample) should serve as a good simple sample.